# How to parallelise the execution of differential_evolution in scipy?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, multiprocessing, differential-evolution

I want to run in multiple cores scipy's `differential_evolution` function with the `workers` parameter.

First, I tried to follow the instructions of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html). However, after testing multiple custom objective functions, I wasn't able to get any output for my optimisation (as if the execution was frozen).

After that, I performed the same example given in the documentation, by using as objective function scipy's `rosen` function:

```
bounds = [...]
result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, strategy = 'rand1bin', workers = 5)
```

This time, everything worked perfectly. So then I tried to define my "own" `rosen` function, to check if the problem was indeed due to the definition of my previous functions or something weird was going on:

```
def rosen_custom(x):
    """
    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    r = np.sum(100.0 * (x[1:] - x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1 - x[:-1])**2.0, axis=0)
    return r

bounds = [...]
result = differential_evolution(rosen_custom, bounds, strategy = 'rand1bin', workers = 5)
```

To my surprise, when I tried to execute the previous chunk of code, it got frozen again and no output whatsoever was given.

Does anyone know why this is happening? The `rosen_custom` function defined is exactly the same to  scipy's `rosen` function (copied and pasted from the source code).

I am running from a Jupyter Notebook that uses Python 3.8 and my `scipy` version is 1.8.1.

Comment: Try saving ```rosen_custom``` in a separate file and importing it. I think you're getting this warning ```AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'rosen_custom' on <module '__main__'``` but it isn't being shown

Comment: Thanks @Nin17!! I moved the function and it worked properly. The same for my previous custom functions :)